# Converting data into json format

Tags: json

This output is invalide from of json and i want to convert it into valide json data.Can anyone help?

{"uniq_id":"f29fd9215f1dd18ea5b20db5e523833a","crawl_timestamp":"2019-05-16 09:26:02 +0000","item_name":"Garden Bar","item_description":"Includes baby spinach, tomatoes, cucumbers, crispy onions, bell peppers, broccoli, carrots, bacon, shredded cheddar cheese, freshly-made croutons, and crackers. Served with ranch, blue cheese, Italian herb vinaigrette, and honey mustard dressings. Includes individually wrapped spoons and tongs.","item_price":99.99,"item_category":"Create Your Own Garden Bar","restaurant_name":"Ruby Tuesday","review_count":"62","rating":"4.4","uniq_id_for_billing":"c8c1abe8b9cc815400a8d7c2795a580c"} {"uniq_id":"2294c889c01c76090287db5b6d9376e1","crawl_timestamp":"2019-05-16 09:26:02 +0000","item_name":"Premium Garden Bar","item_description":"Includes baby spinach, iceberg lettuce, tomatoes, cucumbers, crispy onions, bell peppers, broccoli, carrots, baby spinach, baby portobello mushrooms, black olives, crumbled bacon, cheddar cheese, blue cheese, freshly-made croutons, and crackers. Served with veggie basil pasta salad and ranch, blue cheese, Italian herb vinaigrette & honey mustard dressings. Includes individually wrapped spoons and tongs.","item_price":119.99,"item_category":"Create Your Own Garden Bar","restaurant_name":"Ruby Tuesday","review_count":"62","rating":"4.4","uniq_id_for_billing":"c8c1abe8b9cc815400a8d7c2795a580c"} {"uniq_id":"6b2a8448a76890c2d2cc51df114ea237","crawl_timestamp":"2019-05-16 09:26:02 +0000","item_name":"Grilled Chicken","item_description":"NA","item_price":29.99,"item_category":"Create Your Own Garden Bar","restaurant_name":"Ruby Tuesday","review_count":"62","rating":"4.4","uniq_id_for_billing":"c8c1abe8b9cc815400a8d7c2795a580c"}

Comment: There are numerous ways of doing it based on which language you are coding in

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you're providing an array but not telling JSON it's an array, stick [ ] around the json and between each JSON element put in a comma.

```
[{
"uniq_id": "f29fd9215f1dd18ea5b20db5e523833a",
"crawl_timestamp": "2019-05-16 09:26:02 +0000",
"item_name": "Garden Bar",
"item_description": "Includes baby spinach, tomatoes, cucumbers, crispy onions, bell peppers, broccoli, carrots, bacon, shredded cheddar cheese, freshly-made croutons, and crackers. Served with ranch, blue cheese, Italian herb vinaigrette, and honey mustard dressings. Includes individually wrapped spoons and tongs.",
"item_price": 99.99,
"item_category": "Create Your Own Garden Bar",
"restaurant_name": "Ruby Tuesday",
"review_count": "62",
"rating": "4.4",
"uniq_id_for_billing": "c8c1abe8b9cc815400a8d7c2795a580c"
}, {
"uniq_id": "2294c889c01c76090287db5b6d9376e1",
"crawl_timestamp": "2019-05-16 09:26:02 +0000",
"item_name": "Premium Garden Bar",
"item_description": "Includes baby spinach, iceberg lettuce, tomatoes, cucumbers, crispy onions, bell peppers, broccoli, carrots, baby spinach, baby portobello mushrooms, black olives, crumbled bacon, cheddar cheese, blue cheese, freshly-made croutons, and crackers. Served with veggie basil pasta salad and ranch, blue cheese, Italian herb vinaigrette & honey mustard dressings. Includes individually wrapped spoons and tongs.",
"item_price": 119.99,
"item_category": "Create Your Own Garden Bar",
"restaurant_name": "Ruby Tuesday",
"review_count": "62",
"rating": "4.4",
"uniq_id_for_billing": "c8c1abe8b9cc815400a8d7c2795a580c"
}, {
"uniq_id": "6b2a8448a76890c2d2cc51df114ea237",
"crawl_timestamp": "2019-05-16 09:26:02 +0000",
"item_name": "Grilled Chicken",
"item_description": "NA",
"item_price": 29.99,
"item_category": "Create Your Own Garden Bar",
"restaurant_name": "Ruby Tuesday",
"review_count": "62",
"rating": "4.4",
"uniq_id_for_billing": "c8c1abe8b9cc815400a8d7c2795a580c"
}]
```